# PHP undefined function session_status()

Tags: php

Please tell my what is wrong

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_status() in /pineapple/includes/api/auth.php on line 8

```
<?php

check_login();
function check_login()
{
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        }
        session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout']) && isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        if ($_GET['_csrfToken'] == $_SESSION['_csrfToken']) {
            unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
            exec("rm /tmp/sess_*");
            header("Location: /");
        }
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        if (!file_exists("/pineapple/includes/welcome/welcome.php")) {
            include('/pineapple/includes/api/login.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            $parsed_url = parse_url("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            if ($parsed_url['path'] != "/") {
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: it's not working, my version is PHP5 5.4.5

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php to test if a function exist or not. It works for built in or user defined functions.

Comment: Did you check your version on the command line or via `phpinfo()`? They can be different and in this case the second is the one that matters.